# Change HTML element into text from database using AJAX / JQuery according to ID

Tags: php, html, jquery, ajax, codeigniter

I'm new to Jquery and ran into a problem in web development. I want to convert html element to paragraph from database based on id from url.

Here my code for now,

```
<script>
var url = window.location.pathname;
var id = url.substring(url.lastIndexOf('/') + 1);

$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#desc").click(function() {
        $("#content").html(id);
        $(this).addClass('active');
        $("#feature").removeClass('active');
        $("#spec").removeClass('active');
    });
    $("#feature").click(function() {
        $("#content").html(id);
        $(this).addClass('active');
        $("#desc").removeClass('active');
        $("#spec").removeClass('active');
    });
    $("#spec").click(function() {
        $("#content").html(id);
        $(this).addClass('active');
        $("#desc").removeClass('active');
        $("#feature").removeClass('active');
    });
});
</script>
```

[Here is the display that i wish](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7J3Dt.png)

I've got the id, but don't know how to display data from the database (tbl_product) based on that id using AJAX / Jquery. I can only change the active class for now, all your advice and suggestions are will be very usefull.

Comment: My question may be stupid but since when you arrive on the page you already have an ID allowing you to find the data in the database, why not fill this paragraph directly in PHP...?
Why use JQuery...?

Comment: because i dont want to reload the page when retrieve data from database, so i use ajax/jquery. When user click on description, feature or specification button, the data show immadiately and jquery change the class button become active

Comment: I understand that you don't want to reload the page but you are talking about an ID present in a URL. This is the URL of the page....?

Comment: yes it is, like www.domain.com/product/1. I just try another way but still using Jquery. First i using php for each to looping and fetch data base on ID. then i change the #content elemen with the data, but it still not working, I try use .html, .val, .text, append(), replaceWith() but none of them are working

Comment: my bad, i add class "d-none" so it won't appear. it's working now

Comment: So much the better if everything works for you now even if I admit that I didn't fully understand what you wanted to do :) Next time give more information, it will help you more easily. Because there you talked about Ajax in your post but you solve your problem with just an addition of class....?

Comment: Yeah its my first time asking question on stackoverflow, and you're right i'm not clear enough to explain my problem. Lucky my code is working now. When you said i can fill the <p>directly in php, i got an idea to fetch the data using for each loopin for every <p> that i need. Then i made it invisible by adding d-none class (bootstrap). But when i calling the id selector of every <p> that contain the data using Jquery, it's not appear, yeah beacause the d-none class. So, i add removeclass d-none when calling the <p> and its work for me, and don't need ajax.

Comment: i know its will be more simple if i use ajax, but i still dont know how to work with that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use ajax like this

```
$("#desc").click(function() {
    $(this).addClass('active');
    $("#feature").removeClass('active');
    $("#spec").removeClass('active');

    $.ajax({
        url: 'product.php?id=' + id
        dataType: 'html',
        contentType: false,
        processData: false,
        beforeSend: function() {
            $('#content').empty();
        },
        error: function() {
            $('#content').append('error');
        },
        success: function(data) {
            $('#content').append(data);
        }
    })
});
```